# «Как мальчишка» — нужны запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Правильно ли расставлены запятые в этом предложении?
*Стивен Флеминг попал в довольно затруднительную ситуацию — он, **как мальчишка,** влюбился в невесту собственного сына.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что в этом предложении "как мальчишка" является сравнительным оборотом, который нуждается в обособлении.
*Стивен Флеминг попал в довольно затруднительную ситуацию — он, **как мальчишка,** влюбился в невесту собственного сына.*

Здесь нет ни тесной связи со сказуемым (оборот можно изъять из предложения без потери смысла), ни возможности замены наречием или существительным в творительном падеже, ни каких-либо других причин, заставляющих отказаться от постановки запятых.

[Постановка запятой перед союзом КАК](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183#:%7E:text=%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D0%9A%D0%90%D0%9A%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F%D1%85%3A&text=%D0%95%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%20%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%20%D0%B2,2.)
[Когда перед союзом «как» не ставится запятая?](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/kogda-pered-kak-ne-stavitsya-zapyataya-primeryi.html#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%C2%AB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%C2%BB%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F,%C2%AB%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%C2%BB%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F.)

Капитану Прохорову все это нравилось, он, **как мальчишка,** радовался притоку свежих сил, охотно и быстро сходился с неопытными оперативниками, умел жить в обстановке дружеских подначек и вышучивания. [Виль Липатов. И это все о нем (1984)]

Для сравнения (оборот не нуждается в обособлении; = *мальчишкой*):
Очень интересно оказалось поспорить, и выглядел он **как мальчишка** лет восемнадцати. [Александр Солженицын. В круге первом, т.1, гл. 1-25 (1968) // «Новый Мир», 1990]

Answer (score 2):

Интересное предложение.

С одной стороны, нет причин, чтобы не обособлять этот оборот. С другой — **семантика** кажется сомнительной, плохо переведенной.

Союз КАК — **универсальный союз,** он имеет значения не только уподобления, но и **приравнивания (тождества)** с оттенком причины при обособлении.  Кроме того, здесь просматривается обстоятельственное (качественное) значение наречия — **по-мальчишески.**

Я бы предложила такой перевод:

(1) *Стивен Флеминг попал в довольно затруднительную ситуацию — он, **СЛОВНО** мальчишка, влюбился в невесту собственного сына* (**замена союза**).

(3) *Стивен Флеминг попал в довольно затруднительную ситуацию — **как мальчИшка** он влюбился в невесту собственного сына* (**инверсия, нет обособления**).